# Error: acc.concat is not a function for my js flat array function?

Tags: javascript, flat

I am trying to write a js flat function like [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

using concat+recursion. However, my code is always throw a acc.concat is not a function error. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Any one can help me with this issue? Thank you so much in advance!

```
   function flatten (arr) {
      return arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
          if (Array.isArray(val)) {
              acc.concat(flatten(val));
          } else {
              return val;
          }
         return acc;
      }, []);
   }
```

Comment: `return val;` in that case, the next step of `reduce`, `acc` is definitely not an array. Therefore, if `val` then is an array, `acc.concat` won't work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it. I modified my code to: function flatten (arr) {
      return arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
          if (Array.isArray(val)) {
              return acc.concat(flatten(val));
          } else {
              return acc.concat(val);
          }
      }, []);
   };  it works

Comment: PS: the previous comment, which i deleted (because it didn't address the issue clearly enough), comes from me reading the code, and from the `acc.concat`, expecting `acc` to have a subtype of `Array<any>`. Then i see `return val;` in a typeguard for "not an array", and get confused: "why is there a case for something, which should never happen?". Just to elaborate on the train of thought, when reading the code.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, you absolutely right. I modify the else to return acc.contact(val), then it works.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple issues:

- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is not an [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) function. It returns a new array which needs to be assigned or returned `acc = acc.concat(flatten(val));` or `return acc.concat(flatten(val));`.
- `val`s don't get added to the accumulator at any point. `return val;` breaks the normal contract of the callback function which is to return the accumulator for the next element to use.

```js
const flatten = a =>
  a.reduce((acc, val) =>
    acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flatten(val) : val)
  , [])
;
   
console.log(flatten([1,2,3,4,[5,6,[7,[8,9]]]]));
```

Additionally, I think `reduce` is not the most appropriate function here. Whenever I find that I'm reducing onto an array and not filtering any elements, I know I can refactor to a [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which is a more specific `reduce`. Prefer `reduce` only when `filter` or `map` aren't easily usable, such as when creating objects.

```js
const flatten = a =>
  [].concat(...a.map(val => Array.isArray(val) ? flatten(val) : val))
;
   
console.log(flatten([1,2,3,4,[5,6,[7,[8,9]]]]));
```

This avoids all of the rather awkward accumulator business.

But if you don't have access to the spread operator and are looking for full compatibility, then `reduce` is again useful because it enables us to call `concat` on each element:

```js
function flatten(a) {
  return a.reduce(function (acc, val) { 
    return acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flatten(val) : val);
  }, []);
}
   
console.log(flatten([1,2,3,4,[5,6,[7,[8,9]]]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you do the step to terminate the recursion before doing the recursion and it's tripping you up.

When you do `if (Array.isArray(val))` you should decide whether to treat `val` as an array and go into `flatten` again or not, in which case you can just continue treating it as normal. However, in both cases you want to add `val` to the accumulator, yet in the `else` branch, you simply do `return val`, so on the next execution of the callback, `acc` would be equal to `val` which we already know is not an array.

Instead, in both cases, you should be adding to the array. The only difference is that one time you should recursively `flatten` the other not. This can be simplified if the terminating condition is pulled to be part of `flatten` and not the `reduce` callback:

```js
function flatten (data) {
    if(!Array.isArray(data)) return data;
    
    return data.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(flatten(val)), []);
 }

const input = [[1], [2, [[3]]]];
console.log(flatten(input));
```

So, both times you call `flatten` but if the value is not an array, you simply return it, so you treat it as a normal `acc.concat(1)` - adding a plain value. If you get an array, then you recursively unwrap and flatten it. And since now `flatten` is not guaranteed to get an array, I've renamed the parameter to `data` to avoid confusion.